# Developing an os, user mode, interrupts and syscalls

Tags: operating-system, system-calls, interrupt, interrupt-handling, keyboardinterrupt

in my operating system I need to move to user mode.
I know how to make the move but when I'm in user mode, there are **no interrupts.** so that means for example:

- when I type something in keyboard, the buffer won't fill. so how do I suppose to make system calls to get char from keyboard if the buffer is empty?

If you have some example I can look on system calls and can tell me how I have to make it so I can be in user mode and still get input from keyboard, I would appreciate it.

Hope I make it clear.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean "there are no interrupts"? How is being in user mode prevents interrupts to be delivered?

Comment: What I read is that when you in user mode, you do cli to stop interrupts so there is no interrupts. 
When Im in user mode and divide by zero the system wont crash but the massage "you can't divide by zero" also not printed.

Comment: If there are no interrupts, your system is dead, expired, deceased, nailed to its perch.

Answer (score 2):

In virtually all cpu architectures, there are at least two mechanisms to transition from user (less privileged) to system (more privileged) modes:  traps and interrupts.   Traps result from instructions, such as a division by zero, or a special instruction to entering system mode.   Interrupts are caused by electrical signals which the processor responds to by switching into system mode.   In either case, the processor saves away enough information to be able to resume execution in either mode, and begins execution at a pre-arranged instruction within system mode.

So, a keyboard style device may cause an interrupt when a key is pressed or released, which causes the system to switch to system mode in order to run code specific to that interrupt (typically within a device driver).   That code would typically put the event into a buffer, and awaken anybody who was waiting for it.

A user program could make a trap with some parameters to direct it to the keyboard device driver, where it would extract previous events from the buffer, or wait for events to be available if it were empty.

The user/system distinction is not profound; it is a coarse mechanism for system integrity.

Comment: Can you send me some articles about it? I have to implement it soon

Comment: You better be a fast reader....   A good starting point is Douglas Comer’s book on the XINU Operating System.   I doubt it is in print, but may be in pdf.   It concentrates on the organization and concepts while minimizing cpu implementation details.

Comment: Follow it up with a simple cpu model.   X86 isn’t bad, if you dig around github you will find a few projects which have enough scaffolding that you can graft your own kernel in without much work.